# Is there a word to describe mother in law's brother in law

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

What is mother in law's brother in law called?

Comment: There is no word to describe this better than what you said, *mother in law's  brother in law*.

Comment: I use his first name, it is more polite.

Comment: Unless maybe the brother-in-law is married to the mother-in-law's sister.

Comment: In the Indian tradition, based on the age difference, even distant male relatives are respectfully addressed as "uncle". I speak French as well. To my knowledge, there isn't a term for mother-in-law's brother-in-law, nor the latter's father-in-law in either language.

Comment: @dockeryZ It's possible that the mother-in-law's brother-in-law is Ego's father - or even Ego himself.

Comment: .....who is Ego?

Comment: @dockeryZ The person whose relationships are being discussed.

Comment: In general, other than the catch-all "cousin", (US) English does not have specific words for relationships more complex than "grandparent", "grandchild", "niece", "nephew", "uncle", and "aunt", with "great" potentially prepended N times, or "N times removed" appended.

Answer (score 1):

Uncle- in- law could be better. Or Just uncle.

Comment: Where's your evidence?

Comment: Uncle-in-law! Hmm.. how about aunt-in-law?